# jQuery textbox on change calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've got few check boxes! Everytime the checkboxes is checked it will automatically sum up the total cost:

```
<input type="checkbox" rel="90" alt="30.00">Pearl or White
<input type="checkbox" rel="120" alt="35.00">Natural
<div id="t_balance"></div>
```

jquery to calculate total price

```
function onCheck(){
   var t_balance = 0;
   $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {  
   t_balance += parseFloat($(this).attr("alt")); });
   $("#t_balance").html(t_balance.toFixed(2));         
}
function calculateSum() {
var sum = 0;
$(":text").each(function() {
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
});
$("#t_balance").html(sum.toFixed(2));
 }
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {onCheck(); });
```

Now, 1 discount textinput :

```
<input type="text" id="discount" />
```

**I want the total price deduct the price from discount textinput.** The above code basically will replace the total price, from checkboxes to textinput.

```
$(":text").each(function() {
$(this).keyup(function(){
    calculateSum();
});
});
```

Full code http://jsfiddle.net/boyee007/jZEUz/:

```
function onCheck() {
    var t_balance = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        t_balance += parseFloat($(this).attr("alt"));
    });
    $("#t_balance").html(t_balance.toFixed(2));
}

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(":text").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#t_balance").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    onCheck();
});

$(":text").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Tahir the price deduction is not working if you check on the jsfiddle link

Comment: Do you mean, "if user, selected both check boxed & type 10 in text box, then need to show 55.00"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onCheck() {
    var t_balance = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        t_balance += parseFloat($(this).attr("alt"));
    });
    $("#t_balance").html(t_balance.toFixed(2));

    calculateSum();
}

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = parseFloat( $("#t_balance").text() );

    $(":text").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum -= parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#t_balance").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}

$("input[type=checkbox]").change(onCheck);
$(":text").keyup(onCheck);
```

Call the `calculateSum` from inside the `onCheck` to make the discount get calculated always.

Also simplified the way you bind your handlers since you were creating unneeded overhead..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jZEUz/7/

Answer (score 2):

```
function onCheck() {
    var t_balance = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        t_balance += parseFloat($(this).attr("alt"));
    });
    $("#t_balance").html(t_balance.toFixed(2));
}

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(":text").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#t_balance").html(parseFloat($("#t_balance").text())-sum.toFixed(2));
}
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    onCheck();
});

$(":text").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
        calculateSum();
    });
});
```

Comment: BTW, don't depend on it for functional correctness. Typing a discount, removing with backspace and typing again will deduct both the amounts. I think Gaby's answer is more correct

Answer (score 0):

if your desired output is 55.00, while user selected both check boxed & type 10 in text box, then change your calculateSum function like this,

```
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(":text").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#t_balance").html(($("#t_balance").html()-sum).toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is http://jsfiddle.net/8W92S/ what you're looking for?

Comment: Just checked, neither is mine.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't account for when you "change" the discount, just when you add one :-)